# How can I invoke lodash/fp get and use a default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm using lodash/fp with react and am new to react.  The [documentation for _.get()](https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc#_getpath-object) says you can pass a default value:

> If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is used in its place.

But, in the signature does not show a defaultValue and passing it as third argument does not work, it is ignored:

```
import _ from "lodash/fp"

console.log("first:", _.get("email", profile.profile, "test"))
console.log("second:", _.get("email", profile.profile) ? _.get("email", profile.profile) : "test")
console.log("third:", profile.profile.email)
```

I get in the console:

```
app.js:251 first: undefined
app.js:252 second: test
app.js:253 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Since it is undefined as seen with error in "third" log, why doesn't the first give me empty string instead of undefined?

See [related discussion](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1980).

How do I invoke lodash fp and have a default value used?  Is this what getOr is for?  I tried getOr and am not getting default value.

Comment: The default is only returned if the property doesn't exist, not if the object itself doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar The object does exist in this case.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined` means that `profile.profile` is undefined when you try to log `profile.profile.email`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs you linked to, as you can see, the first argument to _.get is the *object itself*, not a string. If your primary object is `profile`, then that should be the first argument, and the second argument should be a string of the path you want.

`_.get(profile, 'profile.email')` refers to `profile.profile.email`

In `/fp`, [_.get from lodash/fp doesn’t use defaultValue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1980), and the solution is to use getOr, which works fine for me:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vp2opyjkl

Comment: Then why does "second" work when a value is present?

Comment: A value *isn't* present because the first argument is not an object - you used the ternary operator with `'test'` after the `:`, and the condition failed, so the resulting string is `test`.

Comment: I realize issue is I'm using FP version, see updated question.

Comment: Since `_.get` doesn't accept a default value in /fp, the suggestion is to use getOr instead, which works fine for me - see link in answer

Comment: Looks like issue is need to import getOr from lodash explicitly: `import _, { getOr } from "lodash/fp"`.

Comment: The codesandbox is wrong, getOr's signature is (defaultValue, path, object)

Answer (score 3):

Use `_.getOr(defaultValue, path, object)` from `lodash/fp`.

Sources:

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide